# Lateral/longitudinal velocity of a vehicle

Tags: vectors

Having a vehicle with known $V$ and yaw rate, how to get individual components (longitudinal/lateral) of the velocity?

I seem to find a lot of complicated analysis involving chassis, sideslip etc, but I am interested in just approximation based on these two quantities.

I found two options for lateral velocity:

1. $V_y = \psi V$  (where $\psi$ is yaw rate)
2. $V_y = V * \tan \psi$

The longitudinal velocity is then $V_x = \sqrt{V^2 - V_y^2}$.

My guess is that those two can hardly be corrected simultaneously. Which of those two, if any, provides some reasonable approximation to lateral velocity?